# One of my friend's OR friends' wife? (My friend has only one wife)

Tags: sentence-structure, singular-vs-plural, possessives

Anita is Neil's wife. Neil is one of my friends. Now, how do I refer to Anita? Think that I'm telling someone who does not know the couple.

> One of my friend's wife

**OR**

> One of my friends' wife

I know the structure `one of [something]` takes a plural but then, here it is about possession of a singular which should be made plural--> ***"....friends' wife?"*** .

---

This is interesting. **Suppose Neil has many wives. How do I again refer to Anita?**

> One of my friend's wives?

**OR**

> One of my friends' wives?

Comment: Your grammar question seems related to this one: [“One of the document's properties” or “One of the documents' properties”? - duplicate](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/239555/one-of-the-documents-properties-or-one-of-the-documents-properties). Unfortunately, neither that thread or its "duplicate-thread" has a good answer. :)

Comment: Just say "My friend Neil's wife."

Answer (score 28):

The unambiguous way to say this in English is, "the wife of one of my friends".

If you are talking about one friend with multiple wives, you could say "one of my friend's wives".

If you have many friends, each of whom has one wife, you could say "one of my friends' wives". There are many wives, one for each friend, so you must use the plural "wives". Yes, the sentence is then ambiguous, whether each friend has one wife or many.

I understand wanting to say "one of my friends' wife", meaning -- "(one of my friends') wife", that is, you have many friends, each has one wife, and you are talking about the one wife of one friend. But that's just not how we say it in English. It's perfectly logical, but not what we say.

Comment: this is nice. Especially for the unambiguous way! :) +1

Comment: "one of my friend's wives" - that's not correct. Mix of singular/plural with 'one' and "friend's" doesn't work. You're saying "the wives of one of my friend", it just doesn't make sense.

Comment: +1, expect that I'm pretty sure I've heard native speakers use expressions like "one of my friends' wife" in casual speech, and it doesn't sound wrong to my ear -- a bit prone to being misheard and/or misparsed, maybe, but usually there's enough context to make the intended meaning clear, anyway.

Comment: @OllieFord "One of" is modifying "wives", not "friend's". If I say "the big blue truck", "big" and "blue" are both modifying "truck". Suppose instead of "my friend" I named the specific friend. Like, "one of Solomon's 600 wives". In this case "one of" is clearly modifying "wives", not that there are multiple Solomons and I mean that I am referring to one of these.

Comment: "If you have many friends, each of whom has one wife, you could say "one of my friends' wives". There are many wives, one for each friend, so you must use the plural "wives"."
This is completely wrong.

Comment: @Jay ""One of" is modifying "wives", not "friend's""
This explanation is also wrong, and probably explains your mistake in the answer: 'one of' is in fact modifying 'my friends'.

Comment: @Nye Well, I'm not going to get into an argument about it. But I'll repeat my example: If I said, "One of Solomon's 600 wives", would you insist that that must mean that there are many Solomons under discussion and I am speaking of one of them? Or "One of yesterday's posts" must mean that there are many yesterdays, of which I am speaking of one?

Comment: @Jay: Because "my friend's" and "my friends'" are pronounced the same way, this can be tricky; but it helps if you consider "his" and "their", which are pronounced differently. We'd say, "I sent an e-mail to all my friends. One of **their** wives [...]", not "One of **his** wives [...]". Ergo: "one of my friends' wives", not "one of my friend's wives".

Comment: @ruakh Was that comment intended for Nye? Because you've completely agreed with Jay, and you are both correct.

Comment: @Nye No, 'one of' is modifying 'wives'. More accurately, it's modifying "my friends' wives", which is a large group of wives (one per friend, probably). The question is "how do I refer to Anita", and the phrase is referring to one wife out of this collection of wives.

Comment: @DCShannon: No, my comment was intended for Jay -- specifically, for his statement that you can write "one of my friend's wives" if you're talking about a friend with multiple wives. But I now realize that he meant "one of {my friend's wives}", not \*"{one of my friend}'s wives", so my comment was misguided.

Comment: @Jay That example just isn't the same, since Solomon is singular. If there were many Solomons: "One of the Solomons' wife" as given in my answer. (Or "One of one Solomons' wives" for the polygamous Solomon among many.)

Comment: @OllieFord *"one of my friend's wives" - that's not correct. [...] You're saying "the wives of one of my friend", it just doesn't make sense.* No, you're saying **one of the wives of my friend**. It's `one of [my friend's wives]`, not `[one of my friend]'s wives`.

Comment: @OllieFord Well, I've said my piece, you've said yours. I'm not going to argue further.

Comment: @starsplusplus Neither - my thinking is that it's `[one of my friends]'s wife`. Clearly the trailing "s" is redundant, though I believe written (and pronounced?!) In certain circles (parts of US?).

Comment: @Jay I don't mean to argue - you may well be correct, I'm just not convinced. (The ayes have it though!)

Comment: @Kik All manner of correct sentences sound 'ridiculous' to many though, just because the mistake is common enough. (E.g. 'none' is singular, 'data' are plural). I did  slightly address this toward the end of my answer.

Answer (score 8):

While the other answers address the use "one of" well, I think it would be better to just drop that part altogether.

> My friend's wife.

This sounds much less awkward to me and seems pretty clear, with or without including a name. It's understood that you are referring to "one of" your friends, because the only other way it could be interpreted is "my friends' wife", and most people would not assume that your friends share a wife, especially in context of the conversation.

This still works if your friend has many wives. It does not emphasize this fact, which may or may not be a benefit. If that needs to be more clear, "one of my friend's wives" would work.

Comment: I completely agree with you. However, I am not sure it answers the actual question because I am not sure which question is the actual question...

Comment: There are a dozen other ways to refer to that woman. My question is related to English language.

Comment: I would point out that this also works without her name, i.e. just "my friend's wife", and sounds _significantly_ less awkward (to me) than any phrase involving "one of".

Comment: I agree that this also expresses the idea. But saying "one of" is not meaningless extra words. It makes clear that there are many women who are wives of my friends, and I am speaking of one specific such woman. If you simply said "my friend's wife", that could be taken to mean that you only have one friend. If you live in a society where a man can have more than one wife, it would imply he has only one. And it emphasizes that you are speaking of only one and not many. All of that may be irrelevant. Or it may not.

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple friends. Neil is "one of my friend*s*". His one wife is therefore "One of my friend*s*' wife". Likewise, Neil's wives are "One of my friend*s*' wives". You also have the option of rephrasing the above, to 'the wife/wives of one of my friends' or other possible equivalents. 
(Intriguingly, you can introduce one of the multiple wives as "One of one of my friends' wives"!)

Comment: -1, "One of my friends' wife" is not grammatical. "One of" indicates we are talking about one element of a collection. The collection is "my friends' wives". There are multiple wives, and we are referring to one of them.

Comment: I disagree. There are two possible analyses, both of which are grammatical. 1) (mine) I have multiple friends > he is [one of my friends] > she is his wife > she is the wife of [one of my friends] > she is [one of my friends]'s wife. QED. 2) (yours, as I understand it) I have multiple friends > they have (for simplicity) one wife each > there exists a group I call [my friends' wives] > she is one of them > she is [one of my friends' wives]. QED as well.

Comment: "she is the wife of [one of my friends]" is fine. It's *not* equivalent to "she is [one of my friend]'s wife" because that's not how the words get grouped together. We don't have parentheses or brackets in English to override the "order of operations". It's not math.

Comment: "She's not my boss's wife - she's one of my friend's wife." Not a parenthesis or bracket in sight.

Comment: No, no parentheses. That's my point. The sentence is wrong because of the way the words group together. You want "She's not my boss's wife, she's one of my friends' wives."

Answer (score 2):

You are asking many questions so I am going to put your statements followed by how I would interpret them.

> One of my friend's wife

-- Doesn't make sense to me as nothing is plural. (Anita has many clones, but since they are all genetically the same Neil still has only one wife?)

> One of my friends' wife

--The wife of one of my friends

> One of my friend's wives

-- One of the many wives of one of my friends

> One of my friends' wives

-- The collective set of women who are wives to one of my friends

To refer to Anita as one of Neil's wives I would say:

> One of One of my friends' wives

Now in answer to how I would refer to Anita in your initial scenario I would simply say "my friend's wife" as I don't particularly see the need to point out that you have more than one friend.

Comment: Many? Only two, that too they are close as two coats of paint! 1) What if a guy has only one wife and I'm referring to her **and** 2) What if he has many and I'm referring to one of them.

Comment: @MaulikV The first question I see is "Now, how do I refer to Anita?".... So my question is which answer do you *really* want: 1) The best/easiest way to refer to Anita? or 2) Which of the two options is grammatically correct? The latter of which happens to be separated into two separate, albeit related questions.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty easy to get there if you break it down (as you have):

> Neil is one of my friends. Anita is Neil's wife.

Substitute the first sentence there for 'Neil', to get the answer:

> Anita is one of my friends' wife.

---

If Anita isn't enough for Neil:

> Neil is one of my friends. Anita is one of Neil's wives.

Therefore:

> Anita is one of my friends' wives.

Though this actually sounds like a colloquial mistake - many native speakers would mistakenly say this in reference to a monogamous relationship; so you might be better off with:

> Anita is one of my friend Neil's wives.

Note that this actually provides the person you're speaking to with more information - you tell them the name of your friend, *and* the name of the friend's wife.

No prior knowledge of either name is needed for this to make sense, although it would *also* make sense if they did know you had a friend name Neil.

Comment: I clearly said, I don't want 'names' there. Explaining someone who does not know the couple. Use pronouns and rewrite the answer please.

Comment: @MaulikV I only used the names in explaining the answer. The actual answer (first and last quotes) only uses the names to *tell* the person you're talking to their names.

Comment: I've edited it to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: -1, You can't just substitute like that. To make a math analogy, that substitution would require parentheses around the "one of my friends'". Once you write it out, "one of" refers to the whole phrase "my friends' wife" which is not plural, and therefore doesn't make sense.

Comment: @DCShannon It's not a perfect substitution, if you notice apostrophe position is different in my post. Poor choice of word maybe. Was just trying to make the choice of wife/wives more obvious.

Comment: ^ Or rather, not that the position is different, but where a direct substitution would read "friends's", I've obviously removed the trailing "s".

Answer (score 0):

"One of my friends' wives" is correct.

If we take the incorrect "One of my friend's wives" the possessive marker is on the noun phrase [One of my friend] which is nonsensical, as we can't take "one of" a singular. Thus the initial noun phrase must be "One of my friends". Therefore the possessive is [One of my friends]'s. Since we use ' instead of 's at the end of plurals ending in s, we just write "One of my friends' wives".

The confusion is that both of them when spoken have the same form, i.e. we don't say "friendses", both "friends'" and "friend's" sound the same. English speakers generally tend to prefer this ambiguous form instead of the clearer form mentioned in the top answer, so it's good to know how to write it.

Comment: If I saw  "One of my friend's wives" I would take it to mean "One of [my friend's wives]" which does make sense...

Comment: For sure, in a culture-independent sense that's perfectly grammatical, which I didn't consider. There's nothing inherently wrong with the structure, it just reflects an uncommon reality in the English-speaking world.

Comment: This is misleading, as it makes it sound like we have "[one of my friends'] wives", rather than "one of [my friends' wives]"

Comment: Doesn't Gollum say 'friendses'?