# Should we use the plural or singular with the possessive case? Ladies' stockings or Lady's?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, possessives

When using the possessive case for purposes of stating what quality a certain object is characteristic of.

Should we use plural or singular form of a noun with an apostrophe?
I used think it should be plural.

1. ladies’ stockings                      or
   lady’s  stockings
2. women’s clothes             or
   woman’s clothes
3. boys’ toy                           or
   boy’s  toy
4. dolls’ house                     or
   doll’s house
5. cow’s milk                       or
   cows’ milk
6. sheep’s wool
   singular or plural

Comment: Related, but it's not a duplicate: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/55384/9161

Comment: The plural is usually used in the context of a business, product etc. intended for a particular group of people - (Ladies' hairdresser, men's outfitter, children's books). However, searching online gives _doll's house_ (I don't know why!), _cow's milk, sheep's wool_.

Comment: Interesting to think about why *doll's house* and *cow's milk* are different from *boys' shoes* or *women's clothes* or whatever.  My guess is that the house or the milk could be (although it is not necessarily) that of one doll or one cow, but *boy's shoes* or *woman's clothes* gives the distinct impression that these are the shoes or clothes of one boy or woman, which is a very strange thing to be selling.

Comment: stangdon, frankly, i was thinking the same. But i found no prove of that guess in any grammar book. One grammar book  i stumbled upon lists  plural and singular versions all together without making any distinction. But it is always worth listerning to native speakers' opnion first. Thank you!

Comment: Stuart F, absolutelly, thank you!!!!!!! )))))))) And English language learners  sure need to consult native speakers. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the stockings or clothes belong to a person who is a woman then write

- a **woman’s** [pair of] stockings
- a woman's clothes

If the stockings or clothes in a store are for women then I'd suggest:

- **women's / ladies'** stockings
- **women's** clothes

A house for a doll would be

- **a doll's** house

A house for *dolls* would be

- a **dolls'** house

milk from a cow is often labelled as

- cow's milk

However when the product is derived from vegetables, manufacturers will omit the apostrophe:

- Sunflower oil (NOT sunflowers' oil)
- Extra Virgin Olive Oil  (NOT Extra Virgin Olives' oil)
- Soya (soy) milk (NOT Soya's milk)
- Coconut water (NOT coconuts' water)

while some animal products will either include the apostrophe or omit it entirely.

- Goat cheese or goat's cheese
- Cow milk or cow's milk
- Sheep wool or sheep's wool
- Lamb wool or lamb's wool

There are exceptions of course, it wouldn’t be English otherwise

- Chicken breast(s) (NOT *chicken’s* breast)
- Duck eggs (NOT *duck’s eggs*)
- Lamb brains (NOT *lamb’s* nor its plural, *lambs’ brain*)
- [Lamb suet](https://www.willowbrookfarm.co.uk/product-page/lamb-suet) (NOT *lamb's* suet)
- Goose liver (NOT *goose's* liver nor *geese's* livers)
- Rabbit-skin glue (Not *rabbit's* glue or *rabbit skin's* glue)

Answer (score 1):

While there may be exceptions, you can follow natural singular or plural.  That is, if you would rephrase as "The stockings of the lady" you should use *lady's* but if you would rephase as "the stocking of the ladies" you should use *ladies'*

Note you would say "Men's stockings" using a plural to mean "stockings made for men".

As, in most of your examples, there is no difference is pronunciation, expect a lot of variation and "mistakes" in text written by native speakers.

"Cow's milk" is "milk of a cow", so would normally be singular.